# Cannot install clock override

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, clock

I tried following [these directions on ubuntuhandbook.com](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/customize-time-date-format-ubuntu-18-04-gnome-panel/) to customize time and date in gnome panel for 18.04.

But I cannot find clock override in Package Manager.

Comment: did you try to search in "Ubuntu Software" App? https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSYdE.png

Comment: @PRATAP I had to install Ubuntu Software app. But a search did not find clock override.

Comment: Ok.. have you not tried to install it from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/739431 clock override extension can be installed easily with "Ubuntu Software" App which comes by default when you install Ubuntu 18.04.. as you said, you dont have "Ubuntu Software" the other way to install is from the above link..

Comment: When I tried, I got Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90148/discussion-between-fixit7-and-pratap).

Comment: Is there an app I can add to desktop that is configurable for date and time? I would like format like   Mar 1 2019 9:43 pm

Comment: could not you configure like `Mar 1 2019 9:43` with `clock override` extension? or your question is completely for an app which can show the date and time separately away from gnome-shell??

Comment: @PRATAP I found this. https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/gnome-tweak-tool-gnome-shell-extension-not-working/18194 Since I have the Mate Desktop, it looks like it will not work. :-(

Comment: 0h.. 0k..you are with Ubuntu Mate..